# How to save the results of each for-loop iteration in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a dataframe with a new column for each iteration of a for loop and save the result of each iteration in it. I'm aware there are several post about similar questions here but I could not find a solution that works for me. The loop should be based on a vector x `x <- c(1 , 2, 3)` like this:

In this simplified example I want to add `x+100*n` with every iteration n (=4). So the result I want should look like the following matrix with n columns:

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 201 | 301 | 401 |
| 102 | 202 | 302 | 402 |
| 103 | 203 | 303 | 403 |

I tried different approaches based on reading in the forum and this was the most promising attempt:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)

repetition <- 4

df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = ))

for (i in 1:repetition){
  df <- replicate(n = repetition, expr = x+i*100, simplify = TRUE)
  colnames(df)[ncol(df)] <- paste0("X", i)
}
```

However this gives me only the result of the last iteration in all 4 columns. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<NA> <NA> <NA>  X4
[1,]  401  401  401 401
[2,]  402  402  402 402
[3,]  403  403  403 403
```

Kind regards and thanks for any help

Comment: (1) Your `df` is a single-column frame with its single column named `"matrix.NA..nrow...3..ncol...."`, unlikely to be what you intend. I suggest you first fill in `ncol=` (perhaps `ncol=repetition`). (2) Your `replicate` expression, when `i` is 1, returns a 3x4 matrix, is that intentional? (3) You are overwriting the _frame_ `df` with the _matrix_ result each time in your for loop, are you wondering why this complete-overwrite is destructive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are redefining the `df` each loop and so the final result is the same as runnning the code once with `i = 4`

To get the desired result, one can realise that a data frame is a list with equal length-rows so we can use `lapply`.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
repetition <- 4

# Loop over `seq_len(repetition)` (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4) and apply function each time
answer_list <- lapply(seq_len(repetition), function(n) x + 100 * n)

# Convert to a data frame taking each list element as a column
answer_df <-
  as.data.frame(
    answer_list,
    col.names = paste0("X", seq_along(answer_list))
  )

answer_df
#>    X1  X2  X3  X4
#> 1 101 201 301 401
#> 2 102 202 302 402
#> 3 103 203 303 403
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code with simply:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = repetition))

for (i in 1:repetition){
  df[,i] <- x + i * 100
}
```

(assuming the typo in the original post of `ncol = )` should be `ncol = repetition`)

Or as mentioned by @r2evans, all in a single go:

```
setNames(data.frame(replicate(n = repetition, expr = x+i*100, simplify = TRUE)), 
         paste0("X", seq_len(repetition)))
```

Output:

```
#   X1  X2  X3  X4
#1 101 201 301 401
#2 102 202 302 402
#3 103 203 303 403
```